# Pyro4 configuration doesn't change

Tags: windows, pyro4

I put the Pyro4 configuration as this in the starting part of my code:
Pyro4.config.THREADPOOL_SIZE = 1
Pyro4.config.THREADPOOL_SIZE_MIN = 1

I check if I tried to run two client code at the same time, it will say ' rejected: no free workers, increase server threadpool size'. It looks like the setting is working, but when I open the console to check the pyro configuration using "python -m Pyro4.configuration", it returns:
THREADPOOL_SIZE = 40
THREADPOOL_SIZE_MIN = 4

Does someone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `python -m Pyro4.configuration`, it will simply print the default settings (influenced only by any environment variables you may have set). I'm not sure why you think that this should know about the settings you added in your own code.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean now.